# How can I suppress the line break before the first item of a list?

Tags: lists, enumitem, inline

Using `enumitem`, I can typeset inline lists with the following

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
%
Text before list.
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item My first item.
  \item My second item.
  \item My third item.
\end{enumerate*}
Text after list.
%
\end{document}
```

However, the output is then

```
 Text before the list 1) .... 2) .... 3) ...
```

whereas I want

```
Text before the list. 1) ....
2) .....
3) ....
```

In other words, after the first item it should works as usual. Is this possible using the `enumitem` package? Or are there other tools available? Or do I have to develop by my own?

Remark: I can enter e.g. a `\\` at the end of an item. But this seems not to be the right solution.

Comment: May I ask why you would want to format the list like that?

Comment: Your Question: The reason is a book by N. Bourbaki, Théories Spectrale printed by Hermann in 1967. I would like to understand whether one can set the layout using LaTeX and KOMA-script to learn more about this special TeX environments. If you have a chance to look into this book you will find the special list on page 2. How to write it "by hand" is obvious, but how to use the features of TeX?

Answer (score 4):

Do you need it just a few times? In this case you can jump to a normal `enumerate` after as many items as you want:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Text before list.
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item My first item.
\end{enumerate*}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
  \item My second item.
  \item My third item.
\end{enumerate}
Text after list.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, I thought about this too but I was not quite sure, whether the spacing between the items are all the same. If yes, then it is a solution. Have to check, if I can put this in an own environment th make it simple. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I went over it but your suggestion will not solve my problem. The inline-modus is what I am searching **but** after the first item the new item should start at a new line and the formatting is not like the one in the usual enumerate-environment. E.g. \br TEXT proceeding the list. 1.) text of the item \br. 2) Text of the new item starting below the word TEXT. \br. I have to look around how I can describe this better using this tool here.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new list type based on `enumerate*`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{itemjoin=\\,label=\arabic*),after=\\}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Text before the list
\begin{myenumerate}
  \item My first item.
  \item My second item.
  \item My third item.
\end{myenumerate}
Text after list.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A first step to a solution of my question is the following code. But I have to streamline all the steps. So please give me some hints if you find some better solutions.

```
    \documentclass[%
        ,paper  = a4    
        ,parskip=half
        ]
    {scrbook}   
    %
    \usepackage{selinput}
    \SelectInputMappings{%
      adieresis={ä},
      germandbls={ß},
      Euro={€},
    }
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    %
    \DeclareNewSectionCommand[% KOMA-Script
        ,beforeskip =  1.5ex plus .2ex minus .1ex
        ,afterskip  = -.333em
        ,font={\large\normalfont\itshape}
        ,indent     = 3em                   
        ,level      = 5
        ,tocindent  = 7.0em
        ,tocnumwidth= 5em
        ]{myremark}     
    %       
    \newcommand{\remark}[1]{%
        \stepcounter{myremark}
        \myremark{#1.---}   
        }
    %
    \newcounter{myitemcounter}[myremark]
    % Motivated by D. Knuth, The TeXbook, Appendix B, page 355
    \setcounter{myitemcounter}{1}
    \newcommand{\myitem}{%
        \stepcounter{myitemcounter}
        \ifthenelse{\value{myitemcounter}=1}%
        {\hspace{0.333em}{\arabic{myitemcounter}})\hspace{0.333em}\ignorespaces}
        {\hspace{3em}{\arabic{myitemcounter}})\hspace{0.333em}\ignorespaces}
        }
    %
    \begin{document}
    %% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    Test vorher
    %
    \remark{Anmerkungen}%
    %
    \myitem Test weites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text 
    Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text

    \myitem Test weites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text 
    Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text


    \remark{Neue Anmerkungen}%
    %
    \myitem Test weites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text 
    Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text

    \myitem Test weites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text 
    Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text Zweites Item. Langer Text
    %
    \end{document}
```

This gives my the output I am expecting.